# probability density function

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In a book the following sentence is told about probability density function at point $a$: "it is a measure of how likely it is that the random variable will be near $a$." What is the meaning of this ?

Answer (score 4):

The meaning is that *if the probability density function is continuous at* $a$, 
then the probability that the random variable $X$ takes on values in a short interval of length $\Delta$ that contains $a$ is approximately $f_X(a)\Delta$. Thus, for example,
$$P\left\{a - \frac{\Delta}{2} < X < a + \frac{\Delta}{2}\right\} \approx f_X(a)\Delta$$
and the approximation improves as $\Delta \to 0$. In other words,
$$\lim_{\Delta \to 0}\frac{P\left\{a - \frac{\Delta}{2} 
< X < a + \frac{\Delta}{2}\right\}}{\Delta} = f_X(a)$$
at all points $a$ where $f_X(\cdot)$ is continuous.

> "it is a measure of how likely it is that the random variable will be near $a$."

If by "near $a$" we mean in the interval $\left(a-\frac{\Delta}{2}, a-\frac{\Delta}{2}\right)$ where $\Delta$ is some fixed *small* positive number,
then, assuming that $f_X(\cdot)$ is continuous at $a$ and $b$, the
probabilities that  $X$ is near $a$ and near $b$ are respectively
*proportional* to $f_X(a)$ and $f_X(b)$ respectively, and so the values
of $f_X(\cdot)$ at $a$ and $b$ respectively can be used to compare
these probabilities.  $f_X(a)$ and $f_X(b)$ respectively are a measure 
of how likely $X$ is to be near $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a meaningful sentence.

For a continuous random variable, the value of the probability density function (pdf) at a point tells us nothing about the probability that the random variable lies near that point. This is because the random variable is continuous, so the probability that it evaluates to any given point is of measure zero.

What is meaningful is to talk about the *integral* of the pdf near the point $a$, as this yields a probability. So a much better sentence would be:

"The definite integral of the probability density function over a small neighbourhood of the point $a$ is a measure of how likely it is that the random variable will be near $a$"

Comment: The definite integral over the probability density function near the point a is the probability that the R.V is less than or equal to a. That's why we call it the cumulative probability function. The length of the interval, over which we integrate the pdf need not be small. Hence the cdf need not tell you how the R.V behaves 'near' the point a. It only tells you how the R.V behaves over an interval(big or small), that includes the point a. I am editing your answer to make it more clear.

Comment: @NikhilPanikkar In my experience, most people would understand that the phrase "definite integral near the point $a$" means an integral from $a - \epsilon$ to $a + \epsilon$; but given your edit, perhaps I am mistaken. I deliberately chose those words as they mirror the language used in the question. However, I do agree that the phrasing "over a small neighbourhood of the point $a$" is more precise.

Comment: I know that when you said 'near', you meant precisely a small neighbourhood. The only point I wanted to stress was that the length of the neighbourhood also matters.If the pdf varies very slowly, you can take a larger neighbourhood, while if it varies rapidly, you would have to consider a smaller neighbourhood. In fact, I made a second edit(adding a second sentence) to your post yesterday. But the edit was rejected for some reason. The edit contained the same sentence contained in my comment to Shu Xiao Li(see below). I am trying to put through the edit now. Lets see if it gets accepted.

Comment: Seems like it has been rejected again. I guess the reason is that I have  already mentioned it in my comments. So it might have seemed repetitive.

Answer (score 1):

It would be illustrative to compare the case with a discrete R.V. With a discrete R.V, the pdf gives the distribution of the probabilities at specific points i.e, it gives you the probability that the R.V takes a particular value. With a continuous R.V, the pdf gives the distribution of probabilities over an interval i.e, it gives you the probability that the R.V takes values in an interval.

Mathematically, if $f(x)$ is the pdf of a discrete R.V - X, then $f(x) = P(X = x)$. If $f(x)$ is the pdf of a continuous R.V - X, then $f(x) = P(X \le x)$.

If $f(x)$ is the probability density function of a continuous R.V, then, $f(x)dx$ is the linear approximation to the *cumulative* probability of $X$ over the interval $[x - dx, x]$. (If you integrate the pdf, then as Colin Bowers said earlier, you get the cumulative distribution function, which gives the *exact* cumulative probability over any arbitrary interval $[x - dx, x]$.

It must also be noted that the 'differential probability' - $f(x)dx$ also depends on the interval $[x - dx, x]$ and not just $f(x)$. How small the interval should be, depends on how rapidly f(x) fluctuates.If $f(x)$ varies very slowly, you can take a larger neighbourhood, while if it varies rapidly, you would have to consider a smaller neighbourhood(for the linear approximation to be reasonably accurate).

Comment: Reason for downvote?

Comment: The three answers that attempted to ascribe meaning to the sentence in question have been down-voted while the single answer that begins with the authoritative statement "It is not a meaningful sentence." has not been down-voted. So perhaps the down-voter(s) agree with that answer and feel that the answers that assign some meaning to the sentence are _not useful._

Answer (score 0):

There are many version of it. In the textbook I used, it says a probability density function$(f(x))$ is just a *nonnegative* function whose integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ is $1$.

What means more is the "Cumulative Distribution Function"$(F(x))$, which is defined as
$$F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf(t)dt$$
This shows the probability of $X\leq x$.

The probability of $X=x$ does not make much sense in continuous case, but as your book says, the probability of $X$ "near" $x$ can be "sort of" described by $f(x)$, as $$P(x_1\leq X\leq x_2)=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}f(t)dt$$
So, by looking at the graph of $f(x)$, you can get a rough idea about how $F(x)$ will look like and get a sense of probability "near" $X=a$.

You can think of the discrete case as simple function of continuous case.

Comment: I hope the textbook you used did not simply define a probability density function to be _any_ **continuous** function whose integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ is $1$. By this definition, $$f(x) = \begin{cases}e^{-x},&x \geq 0,\\0, &x < 0\end{cases}$$ is _not_ a density since it is discontinuous at $x=0$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Yes you're right, I've edited it.

Comment: There is another error which I have just corrected.

Comment: Only thing I guess, is that the interval [x1,x2], would have to be small to give the behaviour of the R.V 'near' a. How small will depend on how rapidly f(x) fluctuates.